# send data from raw socket to udp or tcp socket

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to learn something about sockets in Linux. I have small development board something like raspberry Pi with Linux running inside. Unfortunatly it doesn't have ethernet or usb port.

I have created a dummy network interface and used it like default gateway. I have written a small program using raw sockets listening on dummy interface (then sends all packets over serial line to computer where is program which send this packets to the internet and recieves answers a sends them back).

My problem is when i am trying to ping some public IP address i can see in tcpdump the ICMP requests and responses in both computer and development board. But the ping looks like it does recieve nothing.

I have tryed to use loopback interface instead of dummy interface, but in this case the pings gets looped and the device becomes unresponsible in a while :). But the ping did recieve ICMP response, and TCP connection didn't work.

I also have tryed to use 2 dummy interfaces and create bridge.

I would be very grateful for any advices.

Comment: Solved using tun interface :) it looks like linux is unable to 'bind' raw socket to other type of socket because all packets are transmitted and none are received.